# Lambert lighting model in Shaders for LWJGL2? - porting code

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, pbr

I'm currently working on trying out Physically-Based Rendering techniques with LWJGL2 and through the help of a tutorial that I found [here](http://dominium.maksw.com/articles/physically-based-rendering-pbr/pbr-part-one/), I've decided to work on lambert shading, or the Illumination section of the tutorial. While I've gone through other tutorials with GLSL and have done similar stuff, I'm struggling to get a simple Lambert shader code to work. I'm unsure how old this tutorial is as it doesnt say.

> As of GLSL 130+, in and out are used instead of attribute and varying.
>   GLSL 330+ includes other features like layout qualifiers and changes
>   texture2D to texture.

The tutorial above uses attribute and varying frequently but uses #version 330?. Anyway, this is supposed to be a simple vertex and fragment shader using version #330 to create lambert. I want to port the code from the tutorial to use in LWJGL2, but I'm unsure how to make it work. I'm hoping someone will be generous enough to help get past this rough patch.

My simple Vertex Shader based on thinmatrix's tutorials changed to work with version 330:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 textureCoordinates;

out vec3 colour;
out vec2 pass_textureCoordinates;

void main() {

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    pass_textureCoordinates = textureCoordinates;

}
```

My fragment shader:

```
#version 330
uniform sampler2D modelTexture;

in vec3 colour;
in vec2 pass_textureCoordinates;

//use your own output instead of gl_FragColor
out vec4 out_Color;

void main() {
out_Color = texture(modelTexture,pass_textureCoordinates);
}
```

The vertex shader from the tutorial:

```
#version 330 compatibility

attribute vec3 aVertexTangent;

varying vec3 vvLocalSurfaceNormal ;
varying vec3 vvLocalSurfaceToLightDirection;

void main()
{
vec3 vLightModelPosition = (gl_ModelViewMatrixInverse * gl_LightSource[0].position).xyz;
vvLocalSurfaceToLightDirection = normalize(vLightModelPosition – gl_Vertex.xyz);

vvLocalSurfaceNormal = normalize(gl_Normal);

gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

The fragment shader from the tutorial:

```
#version 330 compatibility

varying vec3 vvLocalSurfaceNormal;
varying vec3 vvLocalSurfaceToLightDirection;

void main()
{
vec3 vNormalisedLocalSurfaceNormal = normalize(vvLocalSurfaceNormal);
vec3 vNormalisedLocalSurfaceToLightDirection = normalize(vvLocalSurfaceToLightDirection);

float fLightIntensity = max(dot(vNormalisedLocalSurfaceToLightDirection, vNormalisedLocalSurfaceNormal), 0.0);

vec3 rgbFragment = vec3(1.0);

rgbFragment *= fLightIntensity;

gl_FragColor.rgb = rgbFragment;
gl_FragColor.a = 1.0 ; // TODO : Worry about materials which allow transparency!
}
```

A lot of these functions don't work in conjunction with LWJGL2.

```
gl_ModelViewMatrixInverse
```

I've noticed that function has been deprecated.

I'm shy of two years trying to follow tutorials about GLSL but there are some things I just don't understand as of yet. It would be much appreciated if one were to educate me on such things.